# Python / regroup several files in list according their sizes with a interval

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, automation, python-itertools

I would like to group several files in a folder according to their size. However, this size must be within an interval of + -200 bytes. That is, if one file weighs 2698752 Bytes, and another weighs 2698700 Bytes, it still fits in the same group. Thus, we will get several lists of all the files of a folder having a size close to 200 bytes between each.
Like this one:

```
[ 'DataGridViewNumericUpDownElements.dll']
[ 'ExpandableGridView.dll']
['Important Document.jpg']
['P1080495.JPG', 'P1080495-2.JPG']
[ 'Redsn0w_win_0.9.15b3.zip']
```

By using `itertools.groupby`, it is relatively easy to group files according to their size. However, I do not understand how to implement my interval in my code ... Indeed, my current code groups the files having an identical size;

Can someone help me to go in the right direction? :)

Here is my code:

```
import os
import os.path
import itertools



#get the filenames in this directory
filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isfile(filename)]

filenames.sort(key=lambda name: os.stat(name).st_size)

#group by size and iterate

for size, items_iterator in itertools.groupby(filenames, key=lambda name: os.stat(name).st_size):
    items = list(items_iterator)
    print items
```

I hope to have been clear :)

Comment: So if you have a 0 byte file, a 200 byte file, and a 400 byte file, would they all end up in the same group? What if there's also a 600 byte file?

Comment: Yes, they would be in the same group. And if we have a file at 600 Byte, another at 400Bytes, and another at 800, they will also be in the same range. The center will be the 600 bytes file ...

Comment: But what if there are 4 files? 0 bytes, 200 bytes, 400 bytes, 600 bytes. All 4 of those would be in the same group?

Comment: A simple trick would be to use `size_in_bytes // 200` and group by that. Then there will be only files within a 200 bytes size window in a group (but it will separate 198 from 202, which is not so good). This may be good enough for you if you decide that it is good enough for you ;)

Comment: I understand the problem. However, there will be in my case no file touching so much in terms of bytes. Clearly, there will not occur loops as you describe it. But indeed, if there are four files as you say, they will all be in the same groups @Aran-Fey

Comment: You may want to look into mean-shift clustering in the scikit-learn package

Comment: Thank you, it seems to me also a good direction to take. I will try to see what I can do with scikit-learn, but I'm sure that from my code it is possible to insert this interval .. @James

Comment: If I divisive **_os.stat (name).st_size / 200_**, there is in my grouping a file at 2 698 700 bytes and another at 2 698 752 bytes. However, if I divide by 300, my two files at 2 698 752 bytes and 2 698 452 bytes are not in the same group ... I have to divide up to 365 to get it. So I do not really understand the logic of what I just did. @zvone

Comment: As I wrote, that is a simple solution, which may or may not be good enough for you. If it is not, you have to make a smarter algorithm, which is not clearly defined, because then you have to decide what to do with the situations like the one mentioned by @Aran-Fey before implementing anything

Comment: I understand better. Thank you for your help, I will try to realize this